# MySQL: display page containing record

Tags: mysql

Assume the following records:

```
ID  Value
=========
1.  No
2.  No
3.  No
4.  No
5.  No
6.  No
7.  Yes
8.  No
9.  No
10. No
```

Each "page" of my records-display contains 5 records (so page 1 has records 1-5, page 2 has records 6-10, and so on ...). I want to display the page that contains the record with the value of `Yes`. Keep in mind that I don't really know where this `Yes` is in the records.

How do I query this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
/* Work out the page */
SELECT @MatchID = ID
  FROM tbl
  WHERE Value = 'Yes'
  ORDER BY ID ASC
  LIMIT 1;

SELECT @Page = CEIL(COUNT(*) / 5)
  FROM tbl
  WHERE ID <= @MatchID;

/* Select the items on that page */
SET @Offset = (@Page - 1) * 5;

SELECT *
  FROM tbl
  ORDER BY ID ASC
  LIMIT @Offset, 5;
```

Note: The above doesn't cater for @MatchID not being found.

I'm unsure whether MySQL limits have to be constants, hence if they do you would have to calculate the offset in PHP, or whatever programming language you're using to connect to MySQL.  Alternatively, maybe this would work, instead of the last SELECT statement in the above example:

```
SET @selectSQL = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT ', @Offset, ', 5');
PREPARE stmt FROM @selectSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe they do have to be constants. Even a simple expression like `LIMIT (1+2)` causes an error.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for checking.  Perhaps the latest edit would work; although, I must admit, I'm not a fan of that kind of thing.

Comment: yeah, that looks like a pretty clever way to do it. I guess I'm not really familiar with using variables in mysql, so I wouldn't be a fan of that either... haha. I think my new edited answer is a lot easier.

Comment: @Brian: Did you see the comment to breiti's answer about IDs not necessarily being consecutive?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that would make things more complicated. But if there are gaps I don't think your solution would work either? Your solution suggests that the row with value = 'YES' is the first item in the set of 5 for the page. But what if it's the 5th item on the desired page? We would probably need a row counting variable. Or maybe your solution does work? I'm just confused now... haha

Comment: @Brian: It's possible that I'm not following you/missing something, but it looks right to me.  Having said that, I've not tried it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM tbl WHERE Value = "Yes" Order by ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

divide the ID through the "records-per-page" (in your case: 5).
Then you get the "page" where the first yes-record exists.

Assuming your ID is Primary Key (auto_increment) and without gaps.

Comment: breiti, ID is a PK and auto increment. However, I can't guarantee there won't be any gaps. There will only be one "Yes" value in the records. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I got this now.
select all records on the same page as the record with Value = 'YES'

```
SET @c:=0;
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl WHERE CEIL((@c:=@c+1) / 5) = (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(temp_table.id) / 5) FROM tbl temp_table WHERE temp_table.id <= (SELECT temp2.id FROM tbl temp2 WHERE temp2.value = 'YES')) ORDER BY tbl.id ASC;
```

Comment: Brian, should I be using FLOOR instead? Page 2.4 is still page 2.

Comment: I thought about that too, but just do some examples.  For instance 11 / 5 = 2.2 ceil would give you 3, and record 11 is on page 3 (records 11 to 15). It works this way because there is no page 0

Comment: Ah, you're right. I actually do not need the page number. I need, in my example, records 6-10. Suggestions?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer for you in a moment. It's hard to do from a cell phone. Lol

Comment: I tested this out in phpmyadmin on one of my tables, and it works

Comment: @James Re-edited my solution, YET AGAIN! haha. Hope it works this time... I did test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Value, ID / 5 AS Page WHERE Value = "Yes"
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT Value, ID DIV 5  + 1 AS Page WHERE Value = "Yes"
```

Comment: This will return records 6-10?

Comment: This will return ONLY the record that has a Value "Yes" - in your case the record with ID 7. You made me think that the query would return a 0 based number that is 0 for a record in 1-5, 1 for 5-10. I will modify the query to reflect a true page number.

Comment: Given an earlier comment, i.e. that there could be gaps in the ID, then presumably this wouldn't work.

Comment: The query gave back to me "2.4". What I really need are records 6-10. Suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact type of the column ID? I presumed it as an INT - I guess not.

Comment: EDIT again to include CASTing on ID.

Comment: It's a PK, auto increment. It's an INT. 7 / 5 + 1 = 2.4

Comment: This worked to get the page number: `SELECT INT(ID / 5 + 1) AS Page FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = "Yes"`. However, I really need records 6-10, not the fact my record is in page 2.

Comment: MySQL has a DIV operator - I didn't know this myself. This performs INTEGER division. A / performs floating point division even thought the operands are INTEGER. Answer edited again :-) perhaps final.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3074/discussion-between-arun-and-stackoverflownewbie)